# Colored close/minimize/resize window icons

Tags: icons, minimize, color

I'd like to change the window action icons (close, resize, minimize) to custom colored ones, but even when putting colored ones in usr/share/icons/action/symbolic, the system converts them into shades of gray, in both black and white theme.
Is there a way to force the system to keep these icons in color ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@user18324 Try asking the devs of [elementary tweaks](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks) (who have made possible the Dark Mode on elementary OS). Maybe you'll get a quicker response and share it here.